# Windows service using Background worker cannot be stopped

Tags: c#, service, windows-services, thread-safety

I have a card reader Windows service using a Background worker to repeatedly call a function.

The problem is that the service cannot be stopped.

I get this error: `error 1061 the service cannot accept control messages at this time`

I have tried

```
new BackgroundWorker { WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
while (!worker.CancellationPending)

this.RequestAdditionalTime(20000);
```

This is the code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{   
    try
    {
        cardReaderEventLog.WriteEntry("Card reader service is in start-pending status.", EventLogEntryType.Information);

        #region setup Card Reader events
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };

        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        serviceStop = false;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        #endregion

        cardReaderEventLog.WriteEntry("Card reader service started.", EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }
    catch (CardReaderNotDetectedException crndEx)
    {
        cardReaderEventLog.WriteEntry(crndEx.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        if (crndEx.InnerException != null)
            cardReaderEventLog.WriteEntry(crndEx.InnerException.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        cardReaderEventLog.WriteEntry(ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
            cardReaderEventLog.WriteEntry(ex.InnerException.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        Environment.Exit(1);
        //throw;
    }
}


protected override void OnStop()
{
    serviceStop = true;

    DisconnectCardReader();
    backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
    backgroundWorker.Dispose();
    this.RequestAdditionalTime(20000);
    // Update the service state to Running.
    ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus();
    serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_STOPPED;
    SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
    cardReaderEventLog.WriteEntry("Card reader service stopped.", EventLogEntryType.Information);
}

protected void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
    while (!worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        DisconnectCardReader();
        try
        {
            InitializeSmartCardWrapper();
        }
        catch (CardReaderNotDetectedException crndEx)
        {
            cardReaderEventLog.WriteEntry(crndEx.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
            if (crndEx.InnerException != null)
                cardReaderEventLog.WriteEntry(crndEx.InnerException.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
    // Do something while waiting for events

}
```

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is this line: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);`. The issue is that it sleeps the thread, so the `OnStop` can't be called because the thread is in a wait state. Usually if you are sleeping threads like that, then you are doing something wrong. Use a timer instead to run something periodically.

Comment: You are correct.

I added a timer and the everything worked!